# Simple GPS guided vehicle

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to familiarize myself with ROS by doing simple DIY projects with the hardware I have.
The goal is try to get a mobile base to navigate a direct/straight path from point A to point B where Point A&B are marked GPS coordinates (waypoints?). The sensors I have are GPS/AHRS sensors. I looked into the tutorials for [ROS navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) for a while before realizing that the stack needs sensor streams from LaserScans or PointClouds.

I dont have any range sensors, and at this point I'm not too worried about obstacle avoidance. I have the GPS/AHRS sensor working independently in ROS and I'm trying to merge this all together with my motor controller. Is there anyway I can use the navigation package without a laser/range sensor? Is there an alternative package that I use to do navigate a direct path from point A to point B? Or, can I somehow use the navigation package with a simple usbcam instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/170131/simple-gps-guided-vehicle/) by [eve](https://answers.ros.org/users/17866/eve/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bharadwaj26](https://answers.ros.org/users/33000/bharadwaj26/) on 2018-08-11**:
Hey Is there any link that you can share to connect bebop to GPS in ros and set waypoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't need obstacle avoidance you can use the navigation stack without a map and without a laser scanner (We've used the configuration based on the [pr2_navigation_apps](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_2dnav_local)). You just need to remove the base_scan sources for the costmaps.

You may still need to use a localization package to provide the estimated position of the robot. We used the [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package and it worked really well.

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2017-05-19**:
Can you give us a link to your source code for the launch files? Working out which topics need feeding in move_base from robot_localization.